# Агрегирующая функция для двоичных данных

Tags: sql, postgresql, запрос, blob

Есть таблица *photos(photo_id, exam_id, photo)*.

*photo_id* - первичный ключ. *exam_id* - внешний ключ, *photo* - двоичные данные (в PostgreSQL - это *bytea*)

Хочу исключительно средствами SQL вывести табличку *(exam_id, photo1, photo2, photo3)*.

Сделал вот такую выборку: *(exam_id, photo_id_1, photo_id_2, photo_id_3)*

```
SELECT photos.exam_id, 
last(CASE WHEN num=1 THEN photos.exam_photo ELSE null END) id_1, 
max(CASE WHEN num=2 THEN photos.exam_photo_id ELSE null END) id_2, 
max(CASE WHEN num=3 THEN photos.exam_photo_id ELSE null END) id_3
FROM  
(SELECT exam_id, 
row_number() over(partition BY exam_id ORDER BY exam_photo_id) num, 
exam_photo_id, exam_photo
FROM examsphotos ORDER BY exam_id) photos 
GROUP BY photos.exam_id;
```

Как переделать этот скрипт так, чтобы в выборке были двоичные данные, никак не придумаю. В лоб не получается, для bytea нет подходящих агрегирующих функций.

Comment: Возьмите три копии таблицы да объедините по равенству exam_id и превышению photo_id. Я не знаю. в каком диалекте SQL это НЕ будет работать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведите тип к text, от которого можно взять max() и после группировки приведите тип обратно к bytea:

```
select exam_id,
       max(CASE WHEN num=1 THEN photo END)::bytea p1,
       max(CASE WHEN num=2 THEN photo END)::bytea p2,
       max(CASE WHEN num=3 THEN photo END)::bytea p3
  from (
   select exam_id,row_number() over(partition by exam_id order by NULL) num, photo::text
     from examsphotos
  ) X
 group by exam_id
```

Либо отказаться от использования агрегирующих функций в пользу оконной функции `lead()`, возвращающей данные из указанных следующих строк. Но в этом случае количество строк в выборке будет равно количеству строк в таблице и надо будет оставить только первые из них, в которых `lead()` соберет все нужные данные.

```
select *
  from (
    select exam_id,
           photo p1,
           lead(photo,1) over(partition by exam_id order by exam_photo_id) p2,
           lead(photo,2) over(partition by exam_id order by exam_photo_id) p3,
           row_number() over(partition by exam_id order by exam_photo_id) rn
      from examsphotos
 ) A
 where rn=1
```

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ