# сортировка по разнице значений mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида

```
offer_id    param_id    value
```

Как вывести `offer_id`, отсортировав значения по разнице `value` у `param_id=3` и `param_id=4`?

Comment: Прочитайте документацию на mysql в части сортировки. Такого бы вопроса не возникло, если бы вы её прочитали

Comment: @ArchDemon, можно просто ответить, [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0?cb=1)

Comment: Сначала получите данные по обоим param_id в одну строку, примерно как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624329/ (т.е. делаете group by и получаете max/min по условию конкретного param_id). А потом сортируете то что получилось по разности `max(case ....) - max(case ...)`